# Python Regex Search Returns Positive Non-Integer Number <1 As Empty String

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python Regex module to search a string, an example of string of interest is "*MBps 2.57".

I am using the following code:

```
 temp_string = re.search('MBps, \d*\.?\d*', line)
 if (temp_string != None):
     temp_number = re.split(' ', temp_string.group(), 1)
```

I want to find instances where MBps is > 0, then take that number and process it.

The code works fine as long as the number after MBps is > 1.  For example, if it's 'MBps 182.57', the RegEx object when converted to string shows 'MBps, 182.57'.

However, when the number after MBps is <1, for example, if it's 'MBps 0.31', then RegEx object returned shows 'MBps' but no number.  It's just an empty string following the first match.

I have tried different regex matching strategies (re.match, re.findall), but none seemed to work correctly.  In the regex101 testing site, it showed the regex expression working but I can't get Python regex module to match the behavior.

Any ideas on why it's happening and how to correct it?

Thanks

Comment: `MBps 0.31` does not contain a comma after `MBps`. Typo?

Comment: Yes, it is a typo.  It should be MBps, 0.31

Answer (score 0):

I would use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = "The first speed is 3.14 MBps and the second is 5.43 MBps"
matches = re.findall(r'\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) MBps\b', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['3.14', '5.43']
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it but it still didn't work for 0.31 MBps.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a way to make this work.

I changed the code to:

```
temp_string = re.search('MBps, [0-9\.]+', line)
if (temp_string != None):
    temp_number = re.split(' ', temp_string.group(), 1)
```

That worked to capture all the numbers.  I think being explicit in Regex matching rather than just \d+ or \d* makes this work better.

Thanks